# Using VUEJS and AXIOS to stream content from a REST API res.data.getReader() is undefined

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, flask, axios

I have the following code in my VUE JS app:

```
  async sendMsg() {
      const messageToSend = this.newMessage.trim(); // Trim and store the message to send
      this.newMessage = ''; // Clear the input field immediately for UX
    
      const botName = "Prometheus";
      const usermessagePayload = {
        content: messageToSend,
        sender: 'user',
        receiver: botName,
        time: util.formatDate.format(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss'),
        sources: []
      };
    
      // Commit user message to the store
      this.$store.commit('SEND_MESSAGE', usermessagePayload);
    
      try {
        const path = `https://<url>/privategptstream?prompt=${messageToSend}`;
        //const param = { prompt: messageToSend };
        console.log("Sending message:", messageToSend);
    
        // Use axios's request config to enable streaming response
        const res = await axios.get(path, { responseType: 'stream' });
    
        // Create a reader to read the response stream
        const reader = res.data.getReader();
        let decodedStream = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
    
        // Stream response to the UI
        while (true) {
          const { done, value } = await reader.read();
          if (done) break;
    
          // Decode and process the streamed chunk
          const chunk = decodedStream.decode(value, { stream: true });
          const answerPayload = {
            content: chunk,
            sender: botName,
            receiver: 'user',
            time: util.formatDate.format(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss'),
          }
    
          // Commit the streamed response to the store
          this.$store.commit('SEND_MESSAGE', answerPayload);

          // After appending a new message, scroll to the bottom
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.scrollToBottom();
          });
        }
    
        // Close the reader after streaming is complete
        reader.releaseLock();
    
        console.log("Streaming complete");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error streaming the answer:", error);
        this.showSnackbar('Failed to get an answer from the server.');
      }
    }
```

I know the URL streams content because when I test it in the browser, I can see the streaming response as they are generated.  I can see in the debugger that res.data has a chunk of text, but getReader is undefined.

The code below is the implementatoin in Python of the flask api which streams:

```
def llm_thread(g, prompt):
    """A function to run the language model in a separate thread."""
    try:
        chat = AzureChatOpenAI(
            azure_endpoint=AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT,
            openai_api_version=OPENAI_API_VERSION,
            deployment_name=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
            openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY,
            openai_api_type=OPENAI_API_TYPE,
            model_name=OPENAI_MODEL_NAME,
            streaming=True,
            callbacks=[ChainStreamHandler(g)],
            temperature=0)
        chat([HumanMessage(content=prompt)])
    finally:
        g.close()

def chain(prompt):
    """Start a new thread to generate tokens."""
    g = ThreadedGenerator()
    threading.Thread(target=llm_thread, args=(g, prompt)).start()
    return g

@app.route('/privategptstream', methods=['GET'])
def privategptstream():
    """Endpoint to generate tokens based on a prompt."""
    prompt = request.args.get('prompt', "What's the meaning of life?")

    def generate_tokens():
        g = chain(prompt)
        try:
            while True:
                token = next(g)
                yield token
        except StopIteration:
            pass
    return Response(stream_with_context(generate_tokens()), mimetype='text/event-stream')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, debug=True)
```

Comment: Where does this code come from and why does it use getReader? Axios doesn't support streams in a browsers afaik because it uses XHR, responseType: 'stream' is for node. Use some fetch-based lib instead if you need this